# Using specific IP's to send HTTP-webrequests

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I've made a programm, which sends HTTP-webrequests.

To secure these requests being sent, I want to have the ability to define an IP, over which the request should be sent.
So in case of the default exit not working the request should be sent via another exit.

I've tried doing that by using IPEndPoint and Sockets but somehow it's not working.

Here is my Code so far

```
   public Response ExecuteRequest(RequestData requestData, NetworkAddress exit) {
         Tracer.Info("Versuche Request über HTTP abzusetzen.");
         if (!PrepareIpEndPoint(Address, exit)) {
            return null;
         }
         Address = new Uri(PlaceholderReplacer.ReplacePlaceholders(Address.ToString(), requestData));
         return RequestExecutor.ExecuteRequest(Address);
      }

      private bool PrepareIpEndPoint(Uri url, NetworkAddress exit) {
         Tracer.Debug(string.Format("Setze den IP-Endpoint auf{0}", exit));
         var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(exit.Address), 0);
         var tempSocket = new Socket(ipEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
         tempSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
         tempSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
         return tempSocket.Connected;
      }
```

the above code is throwing SocketExceptions.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Josh

Comment: Bind is for opening a server socket that can accept client connections. Connect is for connecting to a server socket (as a client). You can't use both of them on the same socket. (you're either server or client)

Comment: `the above code is throwing SocketExceptions` Post the full exception ToString. Witholding error information makes it hard to diagnose the error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line: (it's for opening up a port for accepting clients)

```
   tempSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
```

You want to act as a client by connecting to the server with:

```
   tempSocket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
```

Are you really sure that you want to connet to port zero, i'm pretty sure this is not a valid choice. (standard HTTP = 80, HTTPS = 443)

```
   var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(exit.Address), 80);
```